# How to define a blob storage trigger in Azure DevOps to create a new release?

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, release

I would like to create a new release in Azure DevOps whenever my blob storage container updated.

I mean, I upload a few files to blob storage and when it's finished I want to start a release in DevOps automatically.

Normally we can define several triggers for starting a release. for example when we get a new build pipeline. But I want to trigger it with a blob storage.

I couldn't find any solution for this problem in DevOps.
Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it isn't possible to do straightforward so can be used the workaround:

1. Create [Azure Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage#add-blob-storage-trigger) or [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function) that triggered by Azure Blob Storage Upload-event
2. In the event handler need to initiate start new release by call [Azure DevOps Services REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to create an Azure Logic App with two steps: 1. When a blob is added or modified. 2.http . But in the http I'm having trouble with the required parameters for authentication. I chose Active Directory OAuth as Authentication method. But I'm not sure about tenant, client id, audience and secret. I tried to use the tenant, client id and secret of my application in Azure Active Directory and different things for audience. But still got an error. Can you please help me?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT: I described my problem in a new post, which you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57152558/how-to-find-audience-field-for-active-directory-oauth-authentication-how-to-se